# GitHub Payload from Hook not returning?

Tags: php, git, github, githooks

I have created a simple script located on my public server.

```
if($_GET['secret'])
{
   if($_GET['secret'] == $update_key)
   {
      $payload = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['payload']));

      print_r($payload, TRUE);
   }
}
else
{
   die('You are not authorized');
}
```

And then I created a WebHook in my GitHub Project with an application type of `application/json` that points to the script above.

Now when I push to my repository and then take a look at the body of the response in GitHub on the manage webhooks page, I see that when this was requested, the body of the page was blank.

Why is it not displaying the payload from GitHub?

**NOTE:** I have tried both `$_POST['payload']` and `$_REQUEST['payload']` with the same results.

**Why are you trying to get a hook?**

Simple, I am wanting to call the hook when I create a new release on GitHub and then pull the release notes from the payload and store them in a file called `release.txt` on the same server.

But right now I can't even get the payload to show up.

Answer (score 2):

This caught me out as well.

You actually need to grab the full body of the request, rather than just `$_POST` which you can do by using `file_get_contents('php://input')` to get the body as a string. With that, you should be able to `json_decode` that and get what you need.

Half of the posts about this online still reference `$_POST['payload']` but it seems that isn't used anymore.

Hope this helps!